# What would be the best way to allow users to select from list of games for an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, instantiation

I have an iphone app I'm trying to create where the user can select from a variety of "levels", but I'd like to later be able to change the number of levels, so I don't just want to create a few static buttons, but instead a dynamic list of levels.

The only difference between "levels" in my game are the coordinates used in a mapview, so what I'd really like is a dynamic list of levels which, once clicked, would go to my mapview and automatically populate the coordinate array with the relevant coordinates given the user's level selection.

What would be the best way to implement this? TableView looks like the right format, but the only examples I've seen are lists that don't go to different views once items in the table are selected, let alone passing data from that selection into the next view.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: UITableView would work well, I guess?

Comment: Have you tried building a tableview-based app to see what the limitations of such an approach are?

Answer (score 0):

Use table views if you don't want to go into more advanced code. Once a row is selected, save it's row number (selection) in a singleton (you can use the app delegate for this) and push the view with the map on the navigation controller - which view will "ask" the singleton for the selection.

If you're not afraid to get your hands dirty, you can create dynamic list of UIButtons (or other tapable control) on a UIScrollView. For bonus points, put more than 1 button on a line (kind of like the app icons on the iPhone "desktop"). When one's selected, save the selection in the singleton (like before).